# fetch key names of dictionary into list | python |

Tags: python, json

I have a json data as shown below

**json data**

```
data = '''
{
 "p1":[ {"Name":"A","Age":45} , 
             {"Name":"B","Age":26} ],
 "p2":[ {"Name":"C","Age":25} , 
             {"Name":"D","Age":26} ]
}
'''
```

**My code :**

```
import json

jdata = json.loads(data)
jkey  = jdata.keys()   # (['p1','p2']) 
jheader = []
for row in jkey:
    jheader.append(jdata[row][0])
    break;
```

**How to get only headers into header list**

**Expected output :**

```
header = ['Name','Age']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a list of dicts, and a list with the keys.  Is that what you're after?

```
import json

jdata = json.loads(data)
jheader = []
jrows = []
for key,parts in jdata.items():
    if not jheader:
        jheader = list(parts[0].keys())
    jrows.extend(parts)
```

Comment: why it is converted to list the `jhedaer = list(parts[0] ...`  does it cannot be appended using `append(parts[0].keys()]`

Comment: The `.keys()` function returns a generator.  `append` would just append the generator as a single item.  We want a list so we can use it several times.  You should try it so you can see what it looks like happens, because it's a very common mistake to make.